# Source not Available VS 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, dll, event-handling

Source not available keeps on popping up

I have been searching google for quite some time now and most of the solutions I saw were changing Visual Studio's Settings, tried them but still it doesn't solve the issue

I have the following code

```
[DllImport("BS2dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public static extern bool FiRE(int ptr, int l);
```

in another form

```
public  void createButton2()
        {
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            butt2 = new Button[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
               butt2[i] = new Button();
                int names = i;
               butt2[i].Name = "2" + names.ToString();
               butt2[i].Location = new Point(520 + (x * 31), 70 + (y * 21));
               butt2[i].Visible = true;
               butt2[i].Size = new Size(32, 22);
               butt2[i].BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
               this.Controls.Add(butt2[i]);
               butt2[i].Click += new EventHandler(butt2_2_Click);

                x++;

                if (x == 10)
                {
                    x = 0; y++;
                }
            }

        }
```

event handler

```
private void butt2_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                bool hit;
                int loc;
                Button pushedBtn = sender as Button;
                if (pushedBtn != null)
                {
                    pushedBtn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    pushedBtn.Enabled = false;
                    loc = int.Parse(pushedBtn.Name);
                    if (loc > 29)
                        loc -= 200;
                    else
                        loc -= 20;

                    hit = UnsafeMethodCall.FiRE(objPtr, loc);

                    if (hit == true)
                    {
                       // MessageBox.Show("HIT");
                        pushedBtn.BackColor = Color.Red;                  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("MISS");
                        pushedBtn.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    }

                }
            }//error appears around here
```

even if I comment  `hit = UnsafeMethodCall.FiRE(objPtr, loc);` it still persists

my dll if it helps

```
    void __stdcall FiRE(int *ptr, int l)
    {
        Battleship *dll =  (Battleship *) ptr;
        dll->FIRE(l);
    }

bool Battleship::FIRE( int l) //check if hit or miss
    {

        for(int i= 0; i<17; i++)
        {
            if (board[i]==l)
            {
            hit = true;
            break;
            }
            else
                hit = false;
            break;
            }   

                return hit;

    }
```

My Settings
[Settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83s47i9u2pkw92y/Untitled.png)

so I think my problem is at the event handling part, since even if I remove the call to the dll, error still persists

as you may have noticed, it is a battleship game
when I hit a ship for the first time, it returns true, next attempts would just return false

Comment: Your going to need to pinpoint through debugging which line of code is causing the issue and figure out the source library you are missing.  You can put break-points to see if you got to a certain spot or not and narrow it down.

Comment: when exiting the event handler, error shows up

Answer (score 0):

You should check and make sure all of your source files are being looked at, especially for external libraries that you imported.  Go to the solution and right the properties.  In the window the pops up [below] go to the Debug Source Files.

[image]